login to ASP.NET WebForms app using OpenID (KeyCloak server)
I am solving a KeyCloak login issue from my ASP.NET WebForms application
NET Framework 4.8.1 using OpenID.
I found a few examples, but so far I'm stuck after succeeding in redirecting to the login page of KeyCloak after clicking on LOGIN, then entering username and password and redirecting back to my app. If clicking LOGIN in KeyCloak again I got immediately redirected me back to my app which seems ok since apparently it remembers me as logged in.
Examples which I was using:
https://docs.openathens.net/providers/net-framework-4-5-webforms-openid-connect-example
ASP.NET Framework 4.8 / 4.7 connected with external SSO by OpenId Connect with Authorization Code Grant flow, returns 404 on /signin-oidc
I created a new ASP.NET WebForm 4.8.1 application for my testing and added
the following code:
public class Startup1
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        const string persistentAuthType =
CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType;

app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(persistentAuthType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

        var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = Constants.Authority,
            ClientId = Constants.ClientId,
            ClientSecret = Constants.ClientSecret,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://www.mytest.cz/…out",
            RedirectUri = Constants.RedirectUri,
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile, //.OpenId,
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            //SignInAsAuthenticationType = persistentAuthType, //
Ensure this is set
           };

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions);
        }
    }
}

Clicking the login button does following:
protected void Login_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//login
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge();
}
In the Default.aspx page I have:
Is Authenticated: <%= Request.IsAuthenticated %>
Claim count: <%=
System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.Count() %>
    <h2>GetOwinContext</h2>
    <p>Name: <%=
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity.Name
%></p>
    <p>Is Authenticated: <%=
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
%></p>
    <p>Claims count: <%=
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Claims.Count()
%></p>

However, the page after login returns
Is Authenticated: False
Claim count: 0
Name:
Is Authenticated: False
Claim count: 0

Can you please advise how to determine if the user is logged in, his name and his
assigned roles?
